# I know I'm doing something wrong here with compound interest formula

Tags: java, math, netbeans

Background: doing a budget portfolio program and I am trying to add in a compound interest calculator for a client's savings. Running into some problems here.
So here is the formula I currently have.

```
double comprinc= 25*(Math.pow((1+.05/12),(12*year))); 
       double futurev = saving1*(Math.pow((1+.05/12),((12*year)-1))/(.05/12));
```

This is the following formula broken down into two halves

Total = [ P(1+r/n)^nt ] + [ PMT * (((1 + r/n)^nt - 1) / (r/n)) ]
or

Total = comprinc + futurev

P= principle =25

r= rate=.05

n= number of time interest is compounded

t= the number of years =5( have year currently set to 5)

PMT= initial savings=saving1=25

The problem is that I am testing this against an official compound interest calculator
and the answers I'm getting are no where close.

For example the answer that my program reads out is $7700.28 after 5 years  should be $1739.32

Comment: looks like you have (nt-1) in your second exponent as second argument to pow, when you need nt as the exponenent and then a -1?

Comment: Also this is easier to get right if you introduce N=nt and i=r/n to save re-keying those and to simplify the formulas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key is the -1 is not part of the exponent. I am also trying to simplify here, by reducing calculations and parentheses.

```
double intPerPeriod = .05/12;
double numPeriods = 12*year;    
double comprinc= 25*(Math.pow(1+intPerPeriod,numPeriods)); 
double futurev = saving1*(Math.pow(1+intPerPeriod,numPeriods)-1)/intPerPeriod;
```

Comment: Thanks got me within $7 dollars, think I might have to just use that. I think for some reason the compound interest calculator on investment websites are adding to the percentage. Like this one http://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/compoundinterestcalculator.php  I put in %5 interest and it reads out a report showing 5.12 ?

Comment: The formulas do not take rounding at each step into account. They accept fractions of cents, which perhaps over time add up.

Comment: ahh ok. Well thanks for your help. Spent a couple of hours on just this one part. Hopefully the rest of the app is a lot easier. Thanks again.